# docker-compose and passed-in shell env variables (-e option)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml that references `${host_repo_dir}`. Trying to run the service defined there as follows:

```
docker-compose run -e host_repo_dir=$(pwd) http-api
```

Output:

```
WARNING: The host_repo_dir variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

What gives? I think I'm following https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/.

my environment:

docker version: 18.09.3

docker-compose version: 1.24.0

docker for windows, accessed from WSL

Is this a WSL problem?

Update: setting the env vars in advance sort-of works, but seemingly not always:

```
echo "host repo dir: ${host_repo_dir}, repo name: ${repository_name}, docker repo: ${docker_repository}"
docker-compose run \
    -e host_repo_dir \
    -e repository_name \
    -e docker_repository \
    ${repository_name} || ( cd ${previous_directory} ; exit 3 )
```

output:

```
host repo dir: /c/Users/muellmi1/projects/payoff-2015/http-api, repo name: http-api, docker repo: localhost.localdomain
WARNING: The docker_repository variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

docker_repository was set beforehand by `$1` at the beginning of this script. I now understand that it is required to *export* the variables beforehand. So what worked for me was running `export [VARNAME]` for each of the variables later passed to docker-compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming host_repo_dir is already set *and exported*, you can do.

`docker-compose run -e host_repo_dir http-api`

Comment: indeed, that appears to be working! is the KEY=VAL syntax not working a bug of docker-compose, or am I overlooking something?